# Slack API not showing all private channels a token belongs to

Tags: python, slack, slack-api, channel

I need to get a list of all the public and private Slack channels a particular user token ("xoxp...") belongs to. The problem is that currently the api is returning only some of the private channels, not all of them (but it is returning some). It used to return all, but now some are missing (that used to be found by the user before this). This started happening sometime after March (the last time I queried the API).

I tried:

- Creating a new private channel and adding the user to it to see if it saw that => it does
- Removing the user from the channel it doesn't see when api calling and re-adding the user to the channel => issue remains
- Reinstalling the app to the workspace => issue remains

The workspace only has about 100 channels, including deprecated ones, so I know I'm not hitting the limit.

Here is my code (in Python):

```
def _getChannels(self, _next_cursor=""):
    """ Needs scope  channels:read
    
        Archived channels are included by default. 
        
        INCLUDES private channels the calling user (person whose token is being used) has access to
    """
        
    kwargs = {"limit":1000, 
              "types":"public_channel,private_channel"}
    
    if _next_cursor:
        kwargs["cursor"] = _next_cursor
    
    results_full = self._callApi("conversations.list", "_getChannels()", kwargs)

    results = results_full["channels"]
    next_cursor = results_full["response_metadata"]["next_cursor"]
    
    if next_cursor: # Isn't empty
        results = results + self._getChannels(next_cursor)
    
    return results
    
    
def _callApi(self, call_type, calling_function, kwargs={}):
    """ calling_function is a string for error message reporting """
    
    # New API can't handle booleans or extra params
    pass_error_through = kwargs.get(self.PASS_ERROR_THROUGH, False)
    if self.PASS_ERROR_THROUGH in kwargs:
        kwargs.pop(self.PASS_ERROR_THROUGH)
        
    for key in kwargs:
        if type(kwargs[key]) == bool:
            kwargs[key] = str(kwargs[key]).lower()
    
    # New api raises exceptions instead of returning error, so need to catch
    try:
        result = self._slack_client.api_call(call_type, params=kwargs)
    except Exception as E:
        result = str(E) # You used to be able to just call result["error"]
    
    if "error" in result:
        
        if "ratelimited" in result:
            print("\nRatelimited. Waiting one min before retrying.", flush=True)
            sleep(60)
            return self._callApi(call_type, calling_function, kwargs)
        
        elif not pass_error_through:
        
            error_message = ("ERROR: Call to " + calling_function + 
                             " failed due to " + result + ". " +
                             "\n\nkwargs: " + str(kwargs) + "\n\n--End Message--")
            
            #if "needed" in result:
            #    error_message += "It needs: " + result["needed"]
            
            print() # To provide spacing before the traceback starts
            raise ValueError(error_message)
        
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try scope `groups:read` for private channels?

 https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.list

Documentation says:

 **Information about required scopes** 
*This Conversations API method's required scopes depend on the type of channel-like object you're working with. To use the method, you'll need at least one of the channels:, groups:, im: or mpim: scopes corresponding to the conversation type you're working with.*

Comment: Yes, I have groups read/write, channels read/write, users read, and usergroups read permissions.